# Elasticsearch - Does forcing _id on elasticsearch piles up to only one shard?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Let's say I have 2 documents with the following ids:

id0001
id0002

Since I am forcing the ids of the document, how does elastic search place this in the shard? Will elasticsearch put all of this in the same shard? In other words, how does elastic search compute where to place the documents in a shard?

Answer (score 0):

Each document [is routed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/mapping-routing-field.html) to a specific shard depending on its `_routing` value, which defaults to its ID hash.

```
routing = _routing != null ? hash(_routing) : hash(_id)
routing_factor = num_routing_shards / num_primary_shards
shard_num = (hash(_routing) % num_routing_shards) / routing_factor
```

So `shard_num` will be a direct function of either a specific `_routing` value or the hash of the document's `_id` value.

In your sample, `id0001` and `id0002` would definitely land on two different shards, provided your index has more than one primary shards

Comment: Just a follow up question, when we do not auto generate the value _id, how can we ensure that we are having an evenly distributed documents across the shards?


Does having elasticsearch autogenerate itw own id ensures an evenly distributed documents among the shards?

Comment: Yes, using auto-generated IDs not only makes [indexing faster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_use_auto_generated_ids) but also ensures that the IDs [are properly distributed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/99f88f15c5febbca2d13b5b5fda27b844153bf1a/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/TimeBasedUUIDGenerator.java#L80-L114) over the shards